# Connect Xamarin Forms app with SQL Server using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-6

I have an issue that I fundamentally for the app development that is in production. I have bounced documents and tips from the official Xamarin documentation, but so far I have not been successful in finding documentation or a sequence of tutorials that is specific to me.

I need to connect a Xamarin forms application to a SQL Server database and I want to use Entity Framework to assist in this process. Initially the bank will be local (pc), just for the tests, but then it should be taken to a remote server.

I would then like to know how to do this in the most practical way possible and if there is any documentation or tutorials that can help me in this task.

Comment: never connect a remote client directly to a database server!  See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.